# Multithreaded Programming with two threads sharing data

Tags: java, multithreading

Im supposed to make a program that simulated cars trying to cross a one lane bridge. Cars can come from both west and east sides of the bridge. Heres what I have so far:

Main class:

```
package project4.pkg2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project42 {
    static int wbCars = 0;
    static int ebCars = 0;
    static boolean check = true;

    static void setCheck(int i) {
        if (i == 0){
            check = false;
        }
        else
        {
            check = true;
        }
    }
    static boolean check() {
        return check;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Amount of west-bound cars: ");
        wbCars = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Amount of east-bound cars: ");
        ebCars = in.nextInt();

        WestBound myWest = new WestBound(wbCars);
        Thread westThread = new Thread(myWest);
        westThread.start();

        EastBound myEast = new EastBound(ebCars);
        Thread eastThread = new Thread(myEast);
        eastThread.start();
    }

}
```

EastBound class:

```
package project4.pkg2;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class EastBound implements Runnable {

    int cars = Project42.ebCars;

    EastBound(int cars){
        super();
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //System.out.println(cars + " <- cars");
        while (cars > 0 && Project42.check() == true){
                Project42.setCheck(0);
                System.out.println("An east-bound car is driving on the bridge.");
                try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sumthin weird happened here.");
                }
                Project42.setCheck(1);
                System.out.println("The east-bound car has crossed the bridge.");
                cars--;  
        }
    }
}
```

WestBound class:

```
package project4.pkg2;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WestBound implements Runnable {

    int cars = Project42.wbCars;

    WestBound(int cars){
        super();
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //System.out.println("I made it this far!");
        while (cars > 0 && Project42.check() == true){
                Project42.setCheck(0);
                try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sumthin weird happened here.");
                }

                System.out.println("A west-bound car is driving on the bridge.");

                try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sumthin weird happened here.");
                }
                Project42.setCheck(1);
                System.out.println("The west-bound car has crossed the bridge.");
                cars--;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is in in the main class whichever thread I run first (in this case my westThread), only my west-bound cars cross and none of the east-bound ones do. And vise versa when I put my eastThread to start before my westThread.

Output of program:

```
run:
Amount of west-bound cars: 
2
Amount of east-bound cars: 
3
A west-bound car is driving on the bridge.
The west-bound car has crossed the bridge.
A west-bound car is driving on the bridge.
The west-bound car has crossed the bridge.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Edit:

Thanks for the help. For future viewers with similar problems, here's my solution that fixed it:

Main class:

```
package project4.pkg2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project42 {
    static int wbCars = 0;
    static int ebCars = 0;
    static boolean check = true;

     static synchronized void setCheck(int i) {
        if (i == 0){
            check = false;
        }
        else
        {
            check = true;
        }
    }
    static synchronized boolean check() {
        return check;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Amount of west-bound cars: ");
        wbCars = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Amount of east-bound cars: ");
        ebCars = in.nextInt();

        WestBound myWest = new WestBound(wbCars);
        Thread westThread = new Thread(myWest);
        westThread.start();

        EastBound myEast = new EastBound(ebCars);
        Thread eastThread = new Thread(myEast);
        eastThread.start();
    }

}
```

WestBound:

```
package project4.pkg2;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WestBound implements Runnable {

    int cars = Project42.wbCars;

    WestBound(int cars){
        super();
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //System.out.println("I made it this far!");
        while (cars > 0){
            if (Project42.check() == true){
                Project42.setCheck(0);
                try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sumthin weird happened here.");
                }

                System.out.println("A west-bound car is driving on the bridge.");

                try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sumthin weird happened here.");
                }
                System.out.println("The west-bound car has crossed the bridge. West-bound cars remaining: "+(cars-1));
                cars--;
                Project42.setCheck(1);
                try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sumthin weird happened here.");
                }
        }
    }
        System.out.println("All westbound cars crossed the bridge!");
    }
}
```

EastBound:

```
package project4.pkg2;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class EastBound implements Runnable {

    int cars = Project42.ebCars;

    EastBound(int cars){
        super();
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //System.out.println(cars + " <- cars");
        while (cars > 0){
            if (Project42.check() == true){
                Project42.setCheck(0);
                System.out.println("An east-bound car is driving on the bridge.");
                try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sumthin weird happened here.");
                }
                System.out.println("The east-bound car has crossed the bridge. East-bound cars remaining: "+(cars-1));
                cars--;
                Project42.setCheck(1);
                try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sumthin weird happened here.");
                }
        }
        }
        System.out.println("All eastbound cars crossed the bridge!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `check` volatile (or use `AtomicBoolean`).

Comment: By the way… Why do you need two class definitions for eastbound and westbound? Can't you have two instances from one class?

Comment: @BasilBourque my assignment states "One thread should simulate westbound vehicles and another thread should simulate eastbound vehicles".

Comment: @DontJudgeMe But if the behavior is the same, you needn't implement a pair of classes. One class, two instances, two threads. `new Traffic( "westbound" )` & `new Traffic( "eastbound" )`

Comment: There is no reason why each thread needs to have its own class.  Each thread needs to have its own `Runnable` _instance_, but they can both be instances of the same class.  Like @BasilBourque said though, you probably will need some way (such as an argument or multiple arguments passed in to the constructor)  to tell each thread which direction its cars are supposed to go.

Comment: Does the assignment say specifically to have one thread for each _direction_?  The cars-crossing-a-bridge problem is a fairly common exercise in multithreading, but usually the assignment wants you to create one thread _per car._  You could write a quite reasonable simulation of cars on a bridge using only a single thread, but then it would fail to be an exercise in multithreading.  You should make certain that you really understand what the assignment is asking you to do.

Comment: @jameslarge One thread for each direction, I did that and got a 100% on the assignment soo...  --_O_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two threads are accessing the same resource (e.g. reading/writing the `check` variable) you have to synchronize access to it.

In this case you have to mark `check()` and `getCheck()` as `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn the concept of Java - Thread Synchronization.. it can helps you to use multiple thread to share same resource.
[Try this link to learn more](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm)

Comment: Add answer, not link

Answer (score 0):

As well as synchronization, you need another while loop in the run methods. The run method can reach the end while cars is still non-zero.